# How to make sure that drawn shapes on JPanel is not overlapping?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

What is the best approach to define appropriate coordinates for second shape, taking into account that none should overlap each other? Here is the code for action performed when timer fires:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(allowedToDrawRing || allowedToDrawSquare){

        xRing = (int) ((getWidth() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));
        yRing = (int) ((getHeight() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));

        xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
        ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));

        isOverlaped = xSquare>=xRing && xSquare<=(ringSize+xRing)  && ySquare>=yRing && ySquare<=(yRing+ringSize);

        while (isOverlaped) {
            xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
            ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
            isOverlaped = xSquare>=xRing && xSquare<=(ringSize+xRing)  && ySquare>=yRing && ySquare<=(yRing+ringSize);
        }
        setParamsRing(xRing, yRing, ringSize);
        setParamsSquare(xSquare,ySquare, squareSize);
        repaint();
       }
    }
```

Source code:

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class mull extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static JPanel p;
    Timer timer;
    ActionListener updateProBar;
    private double esize;
    private double maxSize = 0;
    private boolean initialize = true;
    private static int squareX = 50;
    private static int squareY = 50;
    private static int squareSize = 200;
    private static int ringX = 50;
    private static int ringY = 50;
    private static int ringSize = 100;
    private static int frameWidth = 500;
    private static int frameHeight = 500;
    private int jPanelHeight;
    private int jPanelWidth;
    private int i = 0;

    public mull() {
        timer = new Timer(500, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(500);
        timer.start();
    }
    int xRing;
    int yRing;
    int xSquare;
    int ySquare;
    public static boolean allowedToDrawRing = true;
    public static boolean allowedToDrawSquare = true;
    public static boolean isOverlapedOnX = true;
    public static boolean isOverlapedOnY = true;
    public static boolean isOverlaped = true;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (allowedToDrawRing || allowedToDrawSquare) {

            xRing = (int) ((getWidth() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));
            yRing = (int) ((getHeight() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));

            xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
            ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));

//          isOverlaped = (xSquare + squareSize * 2) < (xRing)
//                  || (xSquare) > (xRing + ringSize * 2)
//                  || (ySquare + squareSize * 2) < (yRing)
//                  || (ySquare) > (yRing + ringSize * 2);
//

            while (xSquare >= xRing && xSquare <= (2.0 * ringSize + xRing)
                    && ySquare >= yRing && ySquare <= (yRing + 2.0 * ringSize)) {
                xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
                ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
            }
            setParamsRing(xRing, yRing, ringSize);
            setParamsSquare(xSquare, ySquare, squareSize);

        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void setParamsRing(int xpos, int ypos, int size) {
        mull.ringX = xpos;
        mull.ringY = ypos;
        mull.ringSize = size;
    }
    public void setParamsSquare(int xpos, int ypos, int size) {
        mull.squareX = xpos;
        mull.squareY = ypos;
        mull.squareSize = size;
    }
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (allowedToDrawRing) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawOval(ringX, ringY, ringSize, ringSize);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillOval(ringX, ringY, ringSize, ringSize);

        }

        if (allowedToDrawSquare) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(squareX, squareY, ringSize, ringSize);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(squareX, squareY, ringSize, ringSize);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p = new JPanel();

        f.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                if ((e.getX() >= ringX && e.getX() <= (ringSize + ringX))
                        && (e.getY() >= ringY && e.getY() <= (ringSize + ringY))) {

                    allowedToDrawRing = false;
                }
                if ((e.getX() >= squareX && e.getX() <= (squareSize + squareX))
                        && (e.getY() >= squareY && e.getY() <= (squareSize + squareY))) {

                    allowedToDrawSquare = false;
                }

            }
        });

        f.add(p);
        f.add(new mull());
        f.setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

OK, There is the solution:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (allowedToDrawRing || allowedToDrawSquare) {

            xRing = (int) ((getWidth() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));
            yRing = (int) ((getHeight() - ringSize) * (Math.random()));

            xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
            ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));


            while( !(
                    (xSquare + squareSize) < (xRing)
                    || (xSquare) > (xRing + ringSize )
                    || (ySquare + squareSize) < (yRing)
                    || (ySquare) > (yRing + ringSize)
                    )
                    ){
                xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
                ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));

            }
            setParamsRing(xRing, yRing, ringSize);
            setParamsSquare(xSquare, ySquare, squareSize);

        }
        repaint();
    }
```

Last question: why my application becomes frozen after some iterations of timer if timer was set to low values ??? (in this example 50):

```
public mull() {
        timer = new Timer(50, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(500);
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: not the best answer, but you could use a `for` loop in place of the while and iterate down until nothing overlaps.

Comment: Does it work as it is?  Are xRing, yRing the center of the ring, or the upper left "corner"?

Comment: No, after some iterations it overlaps, xRing, yRing - is used in g.drawOval(xRing, yRing , ringSize, ringSize);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change

```
while ((xSquare + squareSize) >= xRing && xSquare <= (ringSize + xRing)  && (ySquare + squareSize) >= yRing && ySquare <= (ringSize + yRing)) {
   xSquare = (int) ((getWidth() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
   ySquare = (int) ((getHeight() - squareSize) * (Math.random()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it keeps overlapping!

Comment: why do u assume that "ringSize is the radius of the circle, not the diameter." - it is the value of weight and height, and they equal each other - therefore it is diameter!

Comment: @RCola OK, I checked the API: ringSize is the diameter. Check my new condition; I think it will work. I guess you always had overlaps with a square to the left (or higher) of the ring, which I fixed.

Comment: You can have a square with its left edge to the left of the ring, but the right edge of the square is inside the ring.  Your original condition considered that a non-overlap, mine does.